# Perform Find and Insert in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, search

Instead of find and replace i want to perform a find and insert in eclipse.

Eg: I want to insert a line say "@myAnnotation" before each line starting with "public static final String".

How I can do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using the find and replace tool. For this to work, you should check the `Regular Expressions` check box. After that, you can search for `public static final String` and then replace with `@myAnnotation\Rpublic static final String` (where `\R` indicates the new line).

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

1) edit -> Find/Replace

2) fill Find field with: "public static final String"

3) fill Replace with: "@myAnnotation \R public static final String"

4) Check regular expression checkbox.

This should do the work.